# Approximating maxmimal value of Rayleigh Quotient in a set by minimizing distance towards the largest eigenvector.

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is the solution of the following two problems equal?

If no, under what circumstances they will be equal?

$P_1: argmax_{x\in S,x^Tx=1} x^TAx$

$P_2: argmax_{x\in S,x^Tx=1} ||x-\bar{x} ||_2$, where $\bar{x}$ is the eigenvector corrsponding to the largest eigenvalue of A

p.s. $S$ is a convex set